# Can I move from this single-html-page babel/react (usable without a web server) to a compiled single-html-page version?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I have created a simple app that consists of a single `.html` file with and embedded `<script>`. I am happy with how it works now.

But... I have created an unholy mix of React and plain HTML. I have done that because during development I did not have access to `npm` installs and I needed to simply create something quickly and I took the W3Schools suggestions as a start..

My single html page starts with

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3pro.css">
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        table {
          border-collapse: collapse;
        }
```

Then later, my JSX code is added to the body like this:

```
  <body>

    <h2 id="remindersetheader">MyApp v1</h2>
    <div id="reminderset"></div>
    <h2 id="jsonloaderheader">Upload new JSON</h2>
    <div id="jsonloader"></div>

    <script type="text/babel">
        const theReminders = [
            {
```

and a typical JSX return looks like this:

```
            return (
                <div>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr key={`head`}><th>Task</th><th>SubTask</th><th>Done at</th><th>Days Since</th><th>Mark Task</th></tr>
                        {tableRows.map((item) => {
                            const rowStyle = (item.subTask === -1 ? 'task' : 
                                (item.lastSubTask ? 'lastsubtask' : 'subtask'));
                            return (
                                <tr class={`${rowStyle}`} key={`row-${item.task}-${item.subTask}`}>
                                    <td style={{'padding-right':'15px', 'padding-left':'15px'}}>{item.columns[0]}</td>
                                    <td style={{'padding-right':'15px', 'padding-left':'15px'}}>{item.columns[1]}</td>
                                    <td class={`dateCellStyle`}>{item.columns[2]}</td>
                                    <td style={{'padding-right':'15px', 'padding-left':'15px'}}>{item.columns[3]}</td>
                                    <td class={`markCellStyle`}><button type="button" onClick={() => {clickLoadJSONButton(item.task,item.subTask)}}>{(item.subTask==-1?'All Done':'Done')}</button></td></tr>
                            )
                        })}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <button type="button" onClick={() => {resetStorage()}}>Reset</button>
                </div>
            );
```

and the `<script>` part ends with this:

```
        const reminderRoot = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('reminderset'));
        reminderRoot.render(<ReminderSet />);
        const loaderRoot = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('jsonloader'));
        loaderRoot.render(<JSONLoader />);
    </script>
```

Basically, this works as I would like it, but I suspect this is all very much against 'how it should be'.

I wonder if there is a way I can turn this single-page HTML+JS+react.development that can be used without a web server into a single-page HTML+JS+react hat can be used without a web server and for instance then also use more of React's possibilities and move entirely away from the standard HTML elements like `<table>` I am using now.

I have been thinking about refactoring my script code into a separate `src/mycode.jsx` file, compiling that with babel and copying that back into the `<script>` part of my HTML page, but I have no idea if that is a feasible route and what that would mean for the initial `<script>` lines of my HTML page and my current code.

Basically I am looking for a way to keep the 'no web server single page' aspect but use React nonetheless.